# How to update a textview of adapter in an activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a textview in my adapter class and I have to update the textview in activity since I am getting the result in activity. How can i do that? 
This is my activity class. I want to update textview  tv2 with "some text". I have even tried updating textview in adapter but I wasn't successful in doing that.

```
public class TextviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lvText;
ArrayList<TextviewPojo> textviewPojos = new ArrayList<>();
TextviewAdapter textviewAdapter;
TextView tv2;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_textview);

    lvText = findViewById(R.id.lvText);
    textviewAdapter = new TextviewAdapter(textviewPojos,this);
    lvText.setAdapter(textviewAdapter);
    textviewPojos.add(new TextviewPojo("first text","second text"));
    textviewPojos.add(new TextviewPojo("first text","second text"));


  }
}
```

This is my adapter class.

```
public class TextviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  ArrayList<TextviewPojo> textviewPojos = new ArrayList<>();
  Context context;

  public TextviewAdapter(ArrayList<TextviewPojo> textviewPojos, Context context) {
    this.textviewPojos = textviewPojos;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return textviewPojos.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_textview,parent,false);
    }
    TextView tv1,tv2;
    TextviewPojo textviewPojo = textviewPojos.get(position);
    tv1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    tv1.setText(textviewPojo.getText1());
    tv2.setText(textviewPojo.getText2());
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Below is my item layout. - item_textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="filename1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="filename2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: More details please. Add some code snippets.

Comment: Add Your Code Please

Comment: Use listener to update your code in activity from adapter

Comment: I didn't understand what do you want to achieve? @Shrirakshabhat

Comment: I want to update the textview with displayname which i am getting from the method. I am unable to update the textview @Ali

Comment: Textview or textView Data? @Shrirakshabhat

Comment: textview with displayname.

Comment: You mean you want to update your `holder.name` data right? @Shrirakshabhat

Comment: not holder.name, holder.tvDocName i want to update

Comment: I have made the question more simpler now, please have a look.

Comment: @Shrirakshabhat Get position(index) of the object in list, and do `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`

Comment: can u please post some code snippet. @ChiragMittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code do not need to take reference of tvDocName again in selected file just change this code in selected file

```
    public class DocumentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView toolbar_back;
    TextView next;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Survey_vehiclepojo> mylist = new ArrayList();
    My_document_adapter adapter;
    TextView tvDocName;
    View view;
    private int position;
    String displayName = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_document);

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_document, null);
        tvDocName = findViewById(R.id.tvDocName);

//        toolbar_back=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back);
//        toolbar_back.setOnClickListener(this);

//        next=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.next);
//        next.setOnClickListener(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("Pay Slip"));
        mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("Insurance"));
        mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("NA Certificate"));
        adapter = new My_document_adapter(DocumentActivity.this, mylist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /*  @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          switch (v.getId()){
              *//*case R.id.toolbar_back:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.next:
                Intent n=new Intent(DocumentActivity.this,Loan_checklistActivity.class);
                startActivity(n);
                break;*//*
        }
    }*/
    public void Document(int pos) {
        position = pos;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        tvDocName.setText(mylist.get(pos).getPay_slip());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        selectedFile(data);
    }

    private void selectedFile(Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String uriString = null;

            if (uri != null) {
                uriString = uri.toString();
            }
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();

            if (uriString != null) {
                if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                    try (Cursor cursor = DocumentActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Toast.makeText(this, "display" + displayName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //                    Toast.makeText(this, "path is" +path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //   My_document_adapter.Filename(displayName, position);
//                            ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_document, null);
//                            tvDocName = v.findViewById(R.id.tvDocName);
                            tvDocName.setText(displayName);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                displayName = myFile.getName();
                Toast.makeText(this, "display start " + displayName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             //   ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_document, null);
            //    tvDocName = v.findViewById(R.id.tvDocName);
                tvDocName.setText(displayName);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait i put here my whole activity try this

Comment: it worked, the only thing is i need to add tvDocName = findviewbyId(R.id.tvDocName) too .

Answer (score 0):

> in your adapter class change this line

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_document, viewGroup, false);
```

Comment: I tried this but there is no change and my list started showing only first item.

Answer (score 0):

call this where you update you list trough your adpater

```
public void refresh(ArrayList<TextviewPojos> textviewPojos){
this.textviewPojo=textviewPojos;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```